# My cPanel hosting start download files of PHP instead of opening it same problem with Laravel folders it show zero space on index of page

Tags: php, cpanel

My cPanel hosting start download files of PHP instead of opening it same problem with Laravel folders it show zero space on index of page. When I try to run my file on hosting panel it start download a file instead of opening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be its the problem because of PHP version updated. Change the php version from cpanel and remove the additional codes added in .htaccess.